# Elastic Beanstalk stops at EbExtensionPostBuild

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having a problem deploying an EB instance with a custom .ebextensions file. This is the relevant part in that file:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: 'python db_migrate.py'
  02_npm_build:
    command: 'npm install && npm run prod'
```

As you can see, these commands are for migrating my PostgreSQL database (via a Flask backend) and building my React .jsx files.

If I leave these commands out, the deployment completes perfectly well. However, once I put them in, looking at the eb-activity.log it stalls at this part forever (as far as I can tell):

```
[2017-04-10T02:39:24.106Z] INFO  [3023]  - [Application deployment app-613e-170409_223418@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Starting activity...
```

I also get this message on the Health overview in the console (this is after 1 day):

```
Performing application deployment (running for 1 day).
```

I have also tried to deploy it without those container_commands, and then including it back after the successful initial deployment. Then I get the same error message as before in eb-activity.log, and I also get this message on the Health overview:

```
Incorrect application version "app-2a3d-170409_214923" (deployment 1). Expected version "app-2a3d-170409_214923" (deployment 1).
```

Which is very strange because those two versions referenced are the same versions. I don't know what this means!

Comment: I had the same problem, i didn't know how to fix it yet but you can try to  remove all version ( in Application Version tab) and re-deploy. This way fixed my problem.

Comment: No use... :( I have been re-initializing entire applications and I get the same issues...

Comment: i have the same problem. any solution?

Comment: up, same problem, any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

Remove all you container_commands from .ebextensions/

Go ssh to instance, kill process with.

```
sudo killall python
```

Then Deploy new version without container_commands.
And start debuging all your container_commands, one by one on ssh..

Have fun.

Comment: Sorry all, this was an old question and I don't remember how exactly I got around it. However, I can assert that it definitely did have to do with one of my container_commands, so this answer should generally suffice